# What does `class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>` mean?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

The code of `std::function` in gcc has these two lines:

```
template<typename _Res, typename... _ArgTypes>
  class function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)> // <-- unclear to me
```

The first part `template... _ArgTypes` denotes a "parameter pack", i.e., a variadic number of template parameters; that is clear. But the second line is magic.
OK, writing `class function<SmthHere>` means template specialization, so we specialize class `function` with  `_Res(_ArgTypes...)`. The latter looks like a function call with a variable number of arguments. However if `_Res` is `void` and `_ArgTypes` is `int`, we get `void(int)`: this doesn't make sense to me as we can't have a function named `void` and pass an argument `int` to it (??). Is this a specially supported syntax? Could you clarify?

Comment: Not that sure, what you actually mean with _"as we can't have a function called `void` and moreover pass to it an argument `int` (??)."_: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46669ef2aa24e233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about the declaration syntax (which is inherited from C language): here, the syntax `void(int)` does **not** mean that a function named `void` and taking an argument named `int` is being called. Instead, it denotes a **type**, which is a function, taking a parameter of type `int` and returning `void`.

You can read more about function declaration syntax at [C++ Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), there are some examples as well.

Comment: I see now, the idea is: at first, the class `function` is declared as a template with parameter `signature`. Then later two additional template parameters `_Res` and `_ArgTypes` are introduced and the class is defined using `function<_Res(_ArgTypes)>`, and _the key_ is, as you wrote, that `_Res(_ArgTypes)` is actually a type (an existing C syntax for function types). I've seen things like `void (*foo)(int)` but haven't realized it means that `foo` points to a function of type `void(int)`. Thanks!